# sql syntax in preventing sql injection

Tags: php, sql

I'm new to sql and php and I know sql injection is a major problem. I've done some research but I've got a syntax error:

```
$q = $dbc->prepare("INSERT INTO threads (Username,Thread_title,Date_created)
            VALUES('$_SESSION[Username]', ? ,NOW())");
$q = $q->bind_param('s', $_POST['Topic']);
```

is this the right way to go about it?

Comment: what's the error you get ?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Comment: Parameterize the username too. Also take out the `$q = ` on the binding.

Comment: taking out the $q = makes $q an object. it needs to be a string for the mysqli_query